# iframes from square-connect for CC processing not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, square-connect

I'm building a simple SPA with angular that I would like to use to process credit card payments using my Square account.  For security Square wants to use iframes so the CC info never touches my page.

I've read about using `$sce.trustResourceAsUrl()` but square specifically requires that the file be loaded from their CDN (so there's no modifying it).

The https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/adding-payment-form/ doesn't list anything about integrating with AngularJS and I'm not finding any usefully examples.

Anyone have experience successfully embedding square payment forms in an angular1 app that they could point me to? Or are there security risks that prevent this? Thanks!

This is the example file from the documentation:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.squareup.com/v2/paymentform">
<script>
var paymentForm = new SqPaymentForm({blah blah blah});
</script>
<html>
<body>
<label>Card Number</label>
<div id="sq-card-number"></div>
<label>CVV</label>
<div id="sq-cvv"></div>
<label>Expiration Date</label>
<div id="sq-expiration-date"></div>
<label>Postal Code</label>
<div id="sq-postal-code"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not totally sure how to adapt this to work within an angular view.  any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: What code is causing your problems? Are you unable to load the iframes after routing to a new view?

Comment: hey tristansokol, I suspect the problem lays somewhere in the nature of angular and I guess I'm looking for a work around, strange that none of the square documentation addresses angular.  In their example file i include their script file (which i assume is where the magic happens), i can't seem to find a non-minified version of it to find the problem.  I'll include excerpts the example above to illustrate the issue  Thanks for your help.

Comment: And of course you know all that because you wrote the other documentation, sorry about that :-).  Yes, I'm using routing and trying to load the iframes within a view. I'm getting the "SqPaymentForm initialized in Sandbox Mode. See https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/using-sandbox/" message but the inputs aren't visible. I'm not sure where to be looking to trouble shoot this.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

Ah, found the answer in your example code https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/blob/f83e8130ac544b5a9f55d8a11b173b61b8e5cd25/connect-examples/v2/rails_payment/app/views/welcome/angular.html.erb.  Once the directive has completed loading then I need to run `paymentForm.build()`.

iFrames are showing up now.  Thanks!